# Passing function parameters on to fadeOut callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function accepts up to three parameters. I want to be able to pass those parameters on to the callback function so that I am able to check the arguments there in my if statement.

I checked with console log if there are any parameters present in the callback, and there weren't any.

```
function foobar(x, y, z) {
    $("div").fadeOut(300, function() {
        if(arguments.length == 1) {
            //nothing
        } else if(arguments.length == 2) {
            $("div").html(x + y).fadeIn(300);
        } else if(arguments.length == 3) {
            $("div").html(x + y + z).fadeIn(300);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Do I understand right that you want to use x,y and z for the if and else? Whould not be just enought to check if x!=null, y!=null...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arguments` refers to the nearest function, so here it is a `fadeOut` callback. Assign `foobar` function's arguments to the new variable:

```
function foobar(x, y, z) {
    var foobarArguments = arguments;

    $("div").fadeOut(300, function() {
        if(foobarArguments.length == 1) {
            //nothing
        } else if(foobarArguments.length == 2) {
            $("div").html(x + y).fadeIn(300);
        } else if(foobarArguments.length == 3) {
            $("div").html(x + y + z).fadeIn(300);
        }
    });
}
```